# Calling-convention for the 'this' parameter on Linux x64

Tags: c++, linux, calling-convention, abi

I have a scenario where I need to call a function from LLDB (but it could be any C++ API) on Linux x64, from an app written in a different language. For that reason, I need to properly understand the calling-convention and how the arguments are passed.

I am trying to call `SBDebugger::GetCommandInterpreter`, defined as:

```cpp
  lldb::SBCommandInterpreter GetCommandInterpreter();
```

The full header file can be found here: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lldb/blob/master/include/lldb/API/SBDebugger.h

My assumption was that the method would expect a pointer to `SBDebugger` as the `this` argument, in the RDI register. However, when calling the function that way, I get a segmentation fault.

If I look at the disassembly of the function, I see:

```
push   %r13 
push   %r12 
mov    %rsi,%r12 
push   %rbp 
push   %rbx 
mov    %rdi,%rbx
```

The function is reading from both RDI and RSI, despite only expecting the `this` argument. The only explanation I see is that the function is expecting `this` as a value rather than a reference. `SBDebugger` has a size of 16 bytes (one `shared_ptr`), and the calling convention states that a single 16 bytes parameter would be split into the RDI and RSI registers, which matches what I'm seeing.

However, that doesn't make sense to me for multiple reasons:

- If `this` is passed by value, how would it work if the method has any side-effect? The changes wouldn't be reflected on the caller
- The System V ABI states that: `If a C++ object has either a non-trivial copy constructor or a non-trivial destructor 11, it is passed by invisible reference`. The `SBDebugger` does have a custom destructor and copy-constructor:

```cpp
  SBDebugger();

  SBDebugger(const lldb::SBDebugger &rhs);

  SBDebugger(const lldb::DebuggerSP &debugger_sp);

  ~SBDebugger();
```

Despite this, I tried calling the method by passing `SBDebugger` by value and it seems to work, but I get a segmentation fault later when I try to use the returned `SBCommandInterpreter`, so it's possible the method is only returning garbage.

There is something I don't understand about this method call, but I haven't been able to figure out what. What value should I pass in what registers, and why?

Comment: How do you even get the name of the function to call? Dealing with the name mangling of C++ is ugly. I found it's often simpler to create a wrapper `extern "C" lldb::SBCommandInterpreter SBDebugger_GetCommandInterpreter(SBDebugger *self) { return self->GetCommandInterpreter(); }`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yeah my first approach was to use a C++ wrapper to expose the LLDB objects as virtual classes, so they can be easily consumed. Now I just wanted to try removing the C++ wrapper, purely for the technical challenge. Right now I hardcoded the mangled name of the functions but I'll replace it with an actual mangler (assuming I don't switch to something else half-way :p )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I was focusing on the arguments but the trick was the return value. Quoting the System V calling convention:

> A struct, class or union object can be returned from a function in registers only if it is
> sufficiently small and not too complex. If the object is too complex or doesn't fit into the
> appropriate registers then the caller must supply storage space for the object and pass a
> pointer to this space as a parameter to the function.

Basically, because `SBCommandInterpreter` is considered as a complex object, the `GetCommandInterpreter` expects an additional hidden parameter, which is the address to which the return value will be written. So the "real" method signature is:

```cpp
 lldb::SBCommandInterpreter* GetCommandInterpreter(SBCommandInterpreter& returnValue, SBDebugger* this);
```

So the `this` argument is passed by reference as expected, I was just missing an additional hidden argument.